# C simple program doesn't work

Tags: c, gcc

Hello everyone! I'm trying to learn C language and have this trouble:

Example code from book works as it should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* печать таблицы температур по Фаренгейту
и Цельсию для fahr = 0, 20, ..., 300 */

main()
{
    int fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;

    lower = 0; /* нижняя граница таблицы температур */
    upper = 300; /* верхняя граница */
    step = 20;  /* шаг */

    fahr = lower;
    while (fahr <= upper) {
        celsius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
}
```

Output:

> 0 -17
>   20    -6
>   40    4
>   60    15
>   80    26
>   100   37
>   120   48
>   140   60
>   160   71
>   180   82
>   200   93
>   220   104
>   240   115
>   260   126
>   280   137
>   300   148

But code that I've written doesn't do anything!:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int fahr, celsius, lower, upper, step;

    printf("Enter lower temperature:");
    scanf("%d", &lower);

    printf("Enter upper limit:");
    scanf("%d", &lower);

    printf("Enter step:");
    scanf("%d", &lower);

    fahr = lower;
    while (fahr <= upper) {
        celsius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
}
```

Output:

> $ gcc fahr.c -o fahr.out
>   $ ./fahr.out
>   Enter lower temperature:0
>   Enter upper limit:300
>   Enter step:20
>   $

What's wrong?

Comment: In second code each scanf is same `scanf("%d", &lower);`

Comment: +1 for giving us your full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your scanfs read the variable lower.

```
scanf("%d", &lower);
```

This is very typical when you copy and paste sections of code.  Welcome to C we hope you grow to love it as much as the rest of us.

Answer (score 5):

Change this part ->

```
 printf("Enter upper limit:");
    scanf("%d", &lower);

    printf("Enter step:");
    scanf("%d", &lower);
```

to

```
 printf("Enter upper limit:");
    scanf("%d", &upper);

    printf("Enter step:");
    scanf("%d", &step);
```

Answer (score 2):

you have `&lower` thrice. Check your `scanf` it should be `lower`, `upper` & `step`

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
 printf("Enter upper limit:");
    scanf("%d", &lower);
```

it should be

```
 printf("Enter upper limit:");
scanf("%d", &upper);
```

and similarly

```
printf("Enter step:");
scanf("%d", &step);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake exists here:

```
printf("Enter upper limit:");
scanf("%d", &lower);
printf("Enter step:");
scanf("%d", &lower);
```

Change both the scanf's to the below code:

```
scanf("%d", &upper);
scanf("%d", &step);
```

Don't copy paste code, if you want to avoid these kind of mistakes.